# Global variables in erlang

Tags: erlang, global-variables, ejabberd

How to create global variables in Erlang.
One way i have tried is using the mnesia tables.
But for this we have to use database(mnesia) itself.
Is there any other method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other ways are using [ETS tables](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) (simpler to use than Mnesia, but don't offer distribution, persistence or transactions), or using a gen_server process to store global values.

Comment: Can we take write lock on global variables(which i create using gen_server) .

Comment: Usually there is no need to lock it, since the gen_server serialises accesses.  If two requests arrive at the same time, one will be handled before the other.